# How to add relationships to an array and update the asset?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have the following model:

```
 transaction ProduceHalbfabrikat {
   o String halbfabrikatId
    --> Rohstoff[] rohstoff    
}
```

The transaction looks like:

```
return getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Halbfabrikat')
            .then(function (halbfabrikatRegistry) {
               return halbfabrikatRegistry.get(halbfabrikatId);
                })
                // get the asset
                .then(function(halbfabrikatRegistry){
                    halbfabrikatRegistry.rohstoff.push(rohstoff);
                    console.log("Halbfabrikat after PUSH = " + halbfabrikatRegistry.rohstoff);
                        // get the asset again to update the Halbfabrikat 
                        return getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Halbfabrikat')
                        .then(function(updateHalbfabrikatRegistry){
                            // Update the asset
                            return updateHalbfabrikatRegistry.updateAll([halbfabrikatRegistry]);
                        });
```

Now if I try to add the new "rohstoff" to the halbfabrikatRegistry.rohstoff array:

```
"rohstoff": [
      "resource:org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001",
      "resource:org.ba.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_002"
    ]
```

I get the following error:

```
t: Model violation in instance org.xx.xx.Halbfabrikat#111 class org.xx.xx.Rohstoff has value Resource {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001},Resource {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_002} expected a Relationship.
```

in the console.log I can see that the relationship which I would like to add, is a Resource:

```
Halbfabrikat after PUSH = Relationship {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001},Resource {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_002},Resource {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_003}
```

Why is the added value to the array recognized as a Ressource and not a relationship?

If I change the model to

```
transaction ProduceHalbfabrikat {
   o String halbfabrikatId
    --> Rohstoff rohstoff    
}
```

and add the relationships one by one, it works:
console log:

```
Halbfabrikat after PUSH = Relationship {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001},Relationship {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned adding this:
`"rohstoff": [
      "resource:org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001",
      "resource:org.ba.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_002"
    ]`

Is that through CLI or the transaction processor? Could you provide more details?

In the transaction processor function, adding a new relationship will probably require the `factory.newRelationship(String ns, String type, String id)` method.

See: https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop//api/common-factory#newrelationship

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I test my code in the playground, but I think that doesn't matter.
The input to the transaction should already be a relationship ("resource:org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001"). The problem is, that when I add the relation ("resource:org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001") one by one in the transaction, its still a relationship. But when I try to add an array of "Rohstoff" then it changes to a Resource  and update the asset is not possible.

Comment: I see. I think that is unfortunately the case.
--> Rohstoff[] rohstoff is one relationship towards an array of Rohstoffs,
not an array of relationships towards Rohstoffs

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?  I am hitting the same error when trying to use a transaction that contains an array of items as well.  If my transaction definition  has  --> DonationItem item, and the transaction contains "item": "resource:org.iwdr.bc.model.DonationItem#8019"  -- the JS can do donation.items.push(item)).  If I have --> DonationItem[] items and my transaction contains "items": ["resource:org.iwdr.bc.model.DonationItem#8019"] and I try to loop thru items to push (ie. for (oneitem in tx.items){  donation.items.push(oneitem); } I get the error from the OP.

Comment: No, I didn't found a solution yet. Maybe @paul-omahony could help us?

Comment: hi, I'm back after vacation/other stuff: is this still an issue? I see `t: Model violation in instance org.xx.xx.Halbfabrikat#111 class org.xx.xx.Rohstoff has value Resource {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_001},Resource {id=org.xx.xx.Rohstoff#ROH_002} expected a Relationship` above: seems to me you're trying to add resource `org.xx.xx.Rohstoff` to assetRegistry `org.xx.xx.Halbfabrikat` (hence violation). Can you post the whole model, transaction, then say in written form, what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue. I was having this:

```
asset Document identified by documentId {
  o String documentId
  o String docName
  o String documentDescription
  o String docStatus
  o String docAIApprovalStatus
  o String docFinalApproval
  o String docPath
  o String originalname
  o String mimetype
  o Integer size
  --> Member owner
}

@returns(String)
transaction AddDocumentTransaction{
  --> Document document
}
```

so at client side I was constructing Document object and submitting that to transaction. because of which i was facing similar error:

```
{ ValidationException: Model violation in instance org.ibm.dms.AddDocumentTransaction#7d9d5e5237c89b990b69b388a1101cbef99014d285ffcef8deb138fe822a3e75 class org.ibm.dms.Document has value Resource {id=org.ibm.dms.Document#aa781c10-5b6a-11e9-a6b6-4d34f343ceb1} expected a Relationship.
```

Instead i passed all core values of Document object to transaction and then constructed the Document object in transaction processor function. than i did not face this issue. Now my code looks like this:

```
@returns(String)
transaction AddDocumentTransaction{
  o String documentId
  o String docName
  o String documentDescription
  o String docStatus
  o String docAIApprovalStatus
  o String docFinalApproval
  o String docPath
  o String originalname
  o String mimetype
  o Integer size
  o String owneraccnum
}
```

Hope it might help someone.